# Understanding performance hit of an application role in SQL with ASN.NET

Tags: asp.net, performance, sql-server-2005

I use MS SQL Server 2005 application roles in an application. I execute the `sp_setapprole` to start the SPs role and to finish  `sp_unsetapprole.`

"**connection pooling doesn't work**" with application pooling, and there is no way to react on connection "**disconnect event**" (execute `sp_unsetapprole` just before disconnection).

I decide to call `sp_setapprole` at the start of all my SPs and call `sp_unsetapprole` at the end of all SPs.

Have you used SQL application roles? What are your XPs? What about performance hits?

Answer (score 1):

I've rolled my own "approle" in the past, it's not too hard. Create a database role for each type of user (manager, casher, clerk, whatever). Create a database user with the group name (manager_user, casher_user, clerk_user etc). Create accounts for your real users and put them in the database roles. Validate your asp.net users by logging them into the database (open & close a connection), a lookup table or **best** if you use windows authentication and just get their user name from IIS. Check their membership in a database role but log in to the database using role_user. You can secure the database objects via the role_user, the users don't login and don't have access to any sql objects and you get connection pooling.

Comment: I am sorry but I had to down-vote this article.   This is not answering the question.  Rather it's proposing an alternative.  The question specifically is asking for responses from those who have used application roles.   If you have not, then you cannot answer the question so please don't waste other people's time.   Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have not used app roles before, but from what I know about the perf hit is that after setting the application role there is no way to revert to the prev. security context. Thus the connection cannot be reused in pooling. This alone is a huge perf. hit that forces you to think twice about using app roles.

However, the docs say that starting from SQL Server 2005 there is a way to remember the original security context in a kind of cookie returned from sp_setapprole and after that use sp_unsetapprole to revert back to it. So the pooling should work again. If I were you, I would compare the perf. with a couple of simple statements/sprocs.

Any reason you don't use the standard ASP.NET membership API on the application level instead of app roles?

Comment: I do use ASP.NET membership API. SQL application role would be an additional security layer

Comment: I had to down-vote this response because the question is clearly asking for those who have experience using application roles.   Also the first paragraph unnecessarily confuses the reader.   The issue of application pools has been resolved since SQL Server 2005.   See http://blogs.solidq.com/dsarka/Post.aspx?ID=54&title=application+roles+and+connection+pooling

Comment: Be aware that the "solution" created in SQL Server 2005  doesn't work when you live in the real world: if your network connection is broken you'll be unable to call  `sp_unsetapprole`.