# database access impersonation

Tags: sql-server, wcf-security, windows-authentication

My objective is to prevent direct user access to the database server. One way is to create a WCF service or web service in the middle between the front end application and the database server.

First of all, the users will be authenticated to the application. Subsequently the application will connect through the WCF service to perform business logic operations. The WCF service will perform the database related operations by using one windows account. This will prevent other users to directly access the database server, since the permission will only be granted to specific one windows account.

Here are my questions : Even though the database access is only granted to one windows account and the WCF will use this windows account to perform database related operations, is it possible to mark all database related operations with the credential of the logged in user ?

**Update**
Thanks for the replies. Seems like the above scenario is not achievable. I am currently exploring the SQL 2008 Application Role feature. One of the example is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/AppRole.aspx). But after further exploration, apparently there is an issue with the connection pooling.

**Update**
There is a stack overflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216758/sql-server-application-role-performance-hit) regarding SQL Server Application Role

Comment: I don't know of anyone using Application Roles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to have every user set up in sys.server_principals to enable context switching like EXECUTE AS which would mean that they have direct db access anyway.

If you enabled kerberos/delegation, the same applies. Links [One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darwin/archive/2005/10/19/482593.aspx) and [Two](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx)

You'd have to pass in the user name as a parameter on each SQL call, or use CONTEXT_INFO perhaps.

Note: every MS Office user has MSQRY32.EXE which acts as a query tool. If you want no direct DB access, then you need to ensure there are no permissions set or granted

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

If your database and WCF service are on the same box and you do a lot of jiggery pokery to impersonate then it is possible. As soon as you move your DB to another box then it stops working.

This is a known limitation and the reason is impersonation will create a token which will get you to a box but this is not passable to another box. I tried to find the Q&A where MS guy had answered but still havent been able to. Whenever I find it, will update.